# conformal map disc with two removed points

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I need to find all the bijective conformal maps from $D = \{ |z| < 1, z\neq \pm 1/2 \}$ onto itself.

Since this set is not simply connected, I think that the $180°$ degree rotation is the only non-trivial conformal map, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: What is your argument that $z\mapsto -z$ and the identity are the only automorphisms of $D$?

Comment: One path to a solution is to argue that any such map can be extended continuously to a map from the open unit disk to itself (i.e., that it has "removable singularities" at $\pm\frac12$). Then you can use what you know about the automorphisms of the unit disk.

Comment: @Greg Martin Very interesting is there a theorem with a name corresponding to this fact?

Comment: I doubt that there is.

Comment: @GregMartin Wikipedia and Wolfram MathWorld call it [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

By [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)  any such map extends to a holomorphic map of unit disk $\Delta$ into $\Delta$. The extended map is still injective: indeed, if a holomorphic map attains some value $w_0$ at $k\ge 1$ points, it attains all neighboring values at least $k$ times. (This follows from Rouché theorem, or from the argument principle.)

This, the extended map is an automorphism of $\Delta$, i.e., a function of the form 
$$f(z) = \gamma\frac{z-a}{1-\bar az},\qquad |a|<1,\ |\gamma|=1$$ 
Of these, only the identity map and $f(z)=-z$ fix the set $\{\pm 1/2\}$. (A geometric way to see this is to use the fact that $f$ is an isometry in the hyperbolic metric; in particular, it must send the geodesic $[-1/2,1/2]$ onto itself isometrically. Hence $f(0)=0$, etc.)

---

Answer is based on the comment by [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280604/conformal-map-disc-with-two-removed-points#comment2600317_1280604).